# get label value php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to get the label value here :

```
<form action="doinsert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input name="buttonExecute" onClick="execute(document.getElementById('id_student').value)" type="button" value="CHECK  AVAILBLITY" />
    <label name="lab" id="idhere"  ></label></p>
    <input type="hidden"   name="val" value="<?php echo $_POST['lab']; ?>"  />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert Data"/>
```

in doinsert.php

```
$getlabel=$_POST['val'];
echo $getlabel;
```

nothing is printing, any help please ?

Comment: your $_POST['val'] is probably empty or undefined. try `var_dump` instead of `echo`

Comment: your label is id'd with `idhere`, but you're trying to get `id_student` in the JS code.

Comment: your HTML is invalid. That `</p>` doesn't match anything.

Comment: why is it called `$_POST['lab']` in one place and `$_POST['val']` in another? Is it supposed to be the same in both?

Comment: @SDC - The value of val is the previously submitted value of lab. Whether this is what the application requires is another matter.

Comment: I am trying to get the label value via hidden text , because I can't do that directly

Comment: @Norah: Is it a postback answer ? if not, what the hell is that : value="<?php echo $_POST['lab']; ?>"

Comment: When you say "get the label value", which label is it that you want the value of, and what is it that is setting that label in the first place?

Comment: this label <label name="lab" id="idhere"  ></label>

Comment: That label has no value. Is it supposed to be set by the onClick event in the second line?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the label? A `<label>` element does not hold a value and is not submitted as part of a form. It is intended to be used as a caption for an input field; it is not a field itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
<input type="hidden"   name="val" value="Stupid"  />
```

If you see something appearing, then you will find the problem

Answer (score 0):

`echo` will *seem* not to print anything if the value is `null` or `""` (or any empty string thereof).

Try doing:

```
var_dump( $getlabel );
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the value of the input with a name of `val` to an empty string, because you `echo $_POST['lab'];` as its value when the $_POST *hasn't been created yet* - ex nihilo nihil

try viewing the source in the browser and you'll see that the value is empty

Comment: Place your mouse in the browser and right-click it. Then choose `View page source`